# TChart not visible on Android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, pascal

I'm using RAD Studio 10.2 and TeeChart components. I've made a simple TChart component with code shown below. Everything works fine when I compile and run my program on Windows, but when I try to run Android version, TChart component is not visible. No error, nothing, just not showing up. I've tried looking for answer (as I persume, there is some specific thing I should do to make the TChart show up on android) but I just can't find any relevant question. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
Chart1.LeftAxis.Title.Caption:='A1 [-] , A2 [-]';
Chart1.BottomAxis.Title.Caption:='t [s]';
Series1.Title:='A1';
Series2.Title:='A2';
Chart1.Legend.Visible:=True;
Chart1.Series[0].Clear;
Chart1.Series[1].Clear;
for i := 1 to num do Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(Tablica[0][i],Tablica[6][i]);
for i := 1 to num do Chart1.Series[1].AddXY(Tablica[0][i],Tablica[7][i]);
```